# Can't import: PyCharm "Unsolved Reference", Python "No module named ..."

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, python-import

A file named `Item` defines class `Fists`:

```
class Fists(Weapon):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(name="Fists",
                         desc="Just fists",
                         value=0,
                         usable=1,
                         damage=1)
```

A file named `Enemy` in the same directory defines class `Slime`:

```
import Item

class Slime(Enemy):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(enemyhealth=23,
                         enemyweapon=Item.Fists,
                         enemyshield=None)
```

As you see, I'm trying to give instances of `Slime` the ability to instantiate `Fists`, but PyCharm gives the warning: `Unsolved Reference 'Item'`. When run, Python gives an ImportError `No module named 'Item'`. How can make it work? I searched everywhere and nothing helped me.

Comment: Where are the Files in reference to each other?

Comment: did you try to: `from Item import Fists` ? by the way, in python convention we name files with all-lowercase names

Comment: Is `Item.py` in the same directory as `Enemy.py`?

Comment: They are in the same file, and `from Item import Fists` didn't work.

Comment: if they are in the same file then why are you importing it ?

Comment: Sorry, I meant folder.

Comment: Well if you do `from Item import Fists`, then you need to use `Fists` bare.  If you do `import Item`, then you need to do use `Item.Fists`.  If they're in the same file, then you should be able to use `Fists` bare, without any import.

Comment: The problem is that it doesn't recognize that `Item` or even `Fists` exist.

Comment: The script needs to be named `"Item.py"` to be imported as a module via `import` statements.

Comment: Thanks @martineau , I feel so stupid now.

Comment: Bernardozomer: No worries. File extensions are not the universal (although pretty common) way to identify file types. P.S. Your module should have an all lowercase name--by convention. See [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your IDE is in the current directory (use a shortcut or `os.chdir`). If you are using IDLE, in some versions it will not work if you right click and press 'Edit with IDLE'.